# Well-known Synonym: 打墙也是动土

Tags: word

打墙也是动土

[http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/70931373.html?fr=ala&word=打墙也是动土&device=mobile&ssid=0&from=844b&uid=0&pu=usm@0,sz@1320_2001,ta@iphone_1_8.4_3_600&bd_page_type=1&baiduid=B0DC14BD4CFD809A8478494C15B38C6D&tj=zhidao_1_0_10_l1](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/70931373.html?fr=ala&word=%E6%89%93%E5%A2%99%E4%B9%9F%E6%98%AF%E5%8A%A8%E5%9C%9F&device=mobile&ssid=0&from=844b&uid=0&pu=usm@0,sz@1320_2001,ta@iphone_1_8.4_3_600&bd_page_type=1&baiduid=B0DC14BD4CFD809A8478494C15B38C6D&tj=zhidao_1_0_10_l1)

> 动土：指破土建房。意谓为了小事费了大手续，便不如索性做起大事来。
>
> 出处：《红楼梦》第二十九回：“‘打墙也是动土’！已经惊动了人，今日乐得还去逛逛。”

ABC

> **Lit** Building a wall also [requires] moving earth.
>
> **Fig** Building a wall requires almost as much work as building a house, so why not build a house? If one is going to undertake something, why stop at half measures? Why not “go the whole hog”/go “all the way”?

打墙也是动土 doesn't seem to be super well known, I'm looking for something that expresses the idea of "If one is going to undertake something, why stop at half measures?".

Any synonyms?

Comment: 三心二意 is a proverb expressing that something is a half measure. 一心一意 is expressing the opposite, as is 一门心思. I doubt there is an exact equivalent to your phrase.

Comment: 一不做，二不休.............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides 一不做，二不休, there is 好人做到底，送佛送到西. Or simply 既然已经做了，索性做到底.

In English you can say "in for a penny, in for a pound".

Answer (score 0):

不能半途而废
do not give up at half way
or 持之以恒